# SQL queries to determine more than 1 specialize and display in table

Tags: sql, oracle

im using Oracle for doing database personal learning purpose.   For my current knowledge i can't solve this question... here i'll show my problem.

Here is my 2 table structure:

```
CREATE table "HOSPITAL" (
    "HOSPITAL_ID"   NUMBER NOT NULL,  
    "NAME"          VARCHAR2(255),  
    "ADDRESS"       VARCHAR2(255),  
    "BED_CAPACITY"  NUMBER,  
    "CONTACT"       NUMBER,  
    "EMAIL"         VARCHAR2(255),  
    "PAYMENT-SCALE" VARCHAR2(255),  
    constraint  "HOSPITAL_PK" primary key ("HOSPITAL_ID")
);  

CREATE table "HOSPITAL_SPECIALIZE" (  
    "HOSPITAL_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL,    
    "MATERINITY"  VARCHAR2(255),    
    "ENT"         VARCHAR2(255),  
    "DERMATOLOGY" VARCHAR2(255),  
    "ORTHOPEDICS" VARCHAR2(255),  
    constraint  "HOSPITAL_SPECIALIZE_PK" primary key ("HOSPITAL_ID")
);
```

-----Here is the data inside my table-----
[image]

Here is some hospital specialize field, **Yes** mean the hospital was specialize in that particular field.
[image]

**How should i write a SQL that will automatic detect and only list out the hospitals are specialize in  more than 1 area.**

Here is the output i wish to get:
[image]

Is this possible to do it in SQL or maybe my table structure was wrong?

Thank you for reading my question, and sorry about my poor explanation.

Comment: I can only displaying in manually cheap way, not the output that i expect as above picture

Comment: If i add 1 column as specialize and store data as" ENT, maternity, Dermatology". Is that possible to use COUNT to count the values with "," separator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see easy way to do this.

So the cumbersome way is

```
SELECT *
FROM "HOSPITAL"  H
JOIN "HOSPITAL_SPECIALIZE" HS
  ON  H."HOSPITAL_ID" = HS."HOSPITAL_ID"
WHERE DECODE("MATERINITY", 'YES', 1, 0) +
      DECODE("ENT", 'YES', 1, 0) +
      DECODE("DERMATOLOGY", 'YES', 1, 0) +
      DECODE("ORTHOPEDICS", 'YES', 1, 0) >= 2
```

Comment: `iif` is not supported in Oracle.

Comment: @vkp what about `DECODE`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. But in this way will also display the hospital with 1 specialize… I wish it can be only display the hosital & related data with more than 1 specialize

Comment: If i add 1 column as specialize and store data as" ENT, maternity, Dermatology". Is that possible to use COUNT to count the values with "," separator ?

Comment: Why you say will show hospitals with only 1 specialize? Im checking for `>= 2` And yes is possible count the number of time a char appear with [**REGEXP_COUNT**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm)

Comment: so what if in this case, i want to only show the column that with "YES", what should i do?

Comment: That is another question. And you need be more specific. Because is difficult have a query with dinamic number of columns. You need create a dinamic query or pivot and unpivot your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
    a.HOSPITAL_ID, a.NAME, b.MATERNITY, b.ENT, b.DERMATOLOGY, b.ORTHOPEDICS
FROM
    HOSPITAL AS a
    JOIN
    HOSPITAL_SPECIALIZE AS b ON a.HOSPITAL_ID = b.HOSPITAL_ID
WHERE
    CASE MATERNITY WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE ENT WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE DERMATOLOGY WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE ORTHOPEDICS WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by un-pivoting the table, but perhaps you aren't that far into your learning yet. Mark this example (save it somewhere) and come back to it when you learn about pivoting and un-pivoting.

This is a very good learning opportunity. As you have seen, writing a relatively simple query like the one you requested doesn't seem to be easy. In many cases this should suggest there may be a better database design. In this case, you may be better off having an additional table, just for medical specialties. Then your "hospital_specialize" table will just have two columns, for hospital and specialty, and a row for a pair (hospital, specialty) just for the "YES" values in your current design. Then the query would be much simpler - and think about what happens when more specialties are recognized in the industry. Instead of having to alter your table to add one or more columns, you will just have to add one or more values to the "specialties" table.

And then, the report in the format you showed will be obtained by pivoting!

Comment: If i add 1 column as specialize and store data as" ENT, maternity, Dermatology". Is that possible to use COUNT to count the values with "," separator ?

Comment: You can, but that would be a REALLY poor database design. Read about "First Normal Form" - you will see several very good reasons NOT to do it that way.